# Is there a way to find the actual class a reflected field was defined in or find a common base class for child objects?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, polymorphism

I have a field that is defined in a base class and when I use reflection on a child object, I want to retrieve the base class where the field is actually defined. Is there a way to do this in C# .Net 4.0?

Alternatively, is there a way to dynamically find the common base class, given 2 different child classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `FieldInfo.DeclaringType` should point to the Type that actually defines the field.

This actually comes from `MemberInfo` so this will also work for properties, methods, etc..

For the second question. This is untested but should work:

```
public Type GetSharedBaseType(Type a, Type b)
{
    Type tempA = a;
    Type tempB = b;

    while (tempA != null)
    {
        while (tempB != null)
        {
            if (tempA == tempB)
                return tempA;

            tempB = tempB.BaseType;
        }

        tempA = tempA.BaseType;
        tempB = b;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed the `DeclaringType` property.

Answer (score 0):

To find which base class an object belongs to try this..

`obj.GetType().DeclaringType;`

To find out if two objects belongs to same base type you can do something like this.

```
//haven't compiled the code.. you can get the basic idea. Note that `System.Object` will always be the base class for every .Net Object
bool HaveSameBase(Object a, Object b)
{
    Type t = a.GetType();
    List<Type> aTypeList = new List<Type>();
    while(t.BaseType != System.Object)
        {
        aTypeList.Add(t.BaseType);
        t = t.BaseType;
        }

    Type s = b.GetType();
        while(s.BaseType != System.Object)
        {
        if(aTypeList.Any(item => item.Equals(s.BaseType)
             return true;
        s = s.BaseType;
        }

    return false;

}
```